# Rewrite Jquery to Regular Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

How would I rewrite the below code in regular javascript. I dont want to load the jquery library.

```
$(document).ready( function() {
$('.navigation li').click(function() {
$('.navigation li').removeClass('navActive');
$(this).addClass("navActive");
    bgImage = $(this).find('a').attr('href').replace('#', '')+'.jpg';
    $('.background').css("background-image", 'url(images/skins/'+bgImage+')');
});
});
```

Comment: Have a good JavaScript book handy? Why do you not want to load the jQuery library?

Comment: First question that comes to mind is WHY?

Comment: What have you done so far? Share the code what ever you did preferably using jsfiddle or something similar and SO can help..

Comment: Then you will need [getElementsByClassName](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.getElementsByClassName), childNodes or firstChild and wrap in window.onload

Comment: Wouldn't have been too complicated to do this but the `ready` and `css` calls make it so.

Comment: How would you rewrite the code?  Painfully, probably. I kid, but less than a year ago I was in your position, trying to avoid jQuery. I made the jump and never looked back.  This jQuery would be dozens of lines in javascript.  In reality, it still is, but jQuery does all of the hard work for you.

Comment: @SimpleCoder Nope. `css` setter can be replaces easily: `element.style.backgroundImage = 'url(...)'`. `ready` can be replaced by the `DOMContentLoaded` event, or (cross-browser), by placing the `<script>` block before the end of `</body>`.

Comment: @mplungjan because jquery is a pretty hefty download for just 8 lines of code.

Comment: port the functions you need from jQuery or use new ones. That's the best answer anyone can give without doing it for you! I suggest loading jQuery anyway, you don't even need to have jQuery local

Comment: As per @mplungjan -- Why? Not sure his reason for asking that, but here's mine: you are clearly working on visually styling the active page in a navigation menu. *IF* you are using a server-side language (and hey, you may not be), you should do it there. Just because you CAN do something client-side doesn't mean it's the best choice.

Comment: @david But the resulting code would be a LOT more than 8 lines. I applaud the thought of having less code download, but the result would be a lot less terse and you would need to include a getElementsByClassName for older IEs

Comment: @mplungjan he may not need to support older IEs, and regardless, it would still be less than the whole jquery lib.

Comment: jQuery is about the size of a middle sized jpg and will be cached

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The jquery library is fairly complex, and does a lot of stuff behind the scenes. To accurately answer your question you'd need to give us a bit more information, such as:

Which browsers are you planning on supporting? jQuery is very good at staying cross browser compatible, but it relies on some fairly hacky things to do this.  Ideally you don't want to include things like this in your own code, it's better to hide them away in a library.

Do you have control over the page? Could you rewrite this to treat the navigation as a control, so you have things like the image URL in a variable, rather than having to 'extract' it from an `<a />` tag?